# How to get the value from template in .js event if value is dynamic in template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I m working on meteor. I need to get the value from template in event inside my js file. My values are dynamic in template and my code is :

```
<li class="list-group-item"><span><a href="#" style="color:green" id="click_me" value="{{this}}" class="card-link"> {{stuff_Name}} </a>: {{Price}}<i class="fa fa-inr"></i></span></li>
```

I want value of `value={{this}}` in event inside my js file . How can i get it ?

-----Thanks in Advance-----

Comment: Hi @Coder, it wasn't clear if you were asking about how template events work in general or just specifically have to reference the data from the event handler itself.  Either way, I hope my answer will help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Meteor, you can define an event handler in `Template.events` and either retrieve the data from the dom using jQuery or directly from the data context itself.

Here is an example relying on data context.  Assume your template looks like this.

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <ul class="list-group">
    {{#each stuff in lotsOfStuff}}
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <span>
          <a href="#" style="color:green" class="card-link js-card-link">
            {{stuff.stuff_Name}}
          </a>: {{stuff.Price}}<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

Here we are iterating over a collection of items (e.g. `lotsOfStuff`) and creating a list item for each thing using properties of each item (e.g. `stuff_Name` and `Price`).

Now we want to define a click handler to handle a click on any list item.  To do that we define the handler like below.

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  // in ieteor, it's best practice to use a class name starting with
  // `js-` for all event handling...that is why I added the `js-card-link`
  // class to the item.
  'click .js-card-link'(event, instance) {
    // stop the browser from handling the click
    event.preventDefault();

    // get whatever data we care about from the data context of this click
    // e.g. you can access your entire stuff object
    var stuffName = this.stuff_Name;
    var price = this.Price

    // you can even get items from your stuff object that were not displayed on the template
    var id = this.stuffId;

    // now do something with the data
  },
});
```

We can rely on the data context because we are inside of an `{{#each}}` block.  In case you were not inside of a block that defines a usable data context, then you can always use jQuery to get your data.

Here is an example using jQuery.  Again, using this template (note, I have added a data attribute to `<a>`.

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <ul class="list-group">
    {{#each stuff in lotsOfStuff}}
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <span>
          <a href="#" style="color:green" class="card-link js-card-link" data-id="{{stuff.stuffId}}">
            {{stuff.stuff_Name}}
          </a>: {{stuff.Price}}<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>
        </span>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

Here is the modified event handler.

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  // in ieteor, it's best practice to use a class name starting with
  // `js-` for all event handling...that is why I added the `js-card-link`
  // class to the item.
  'click .js-card-link'(event, instance) {
    // stop the browser from handling the click
    event.preventDefault();

    // get the value we stored in the data attribute
    var id = instance.$(event.target).data('id');

    // now do something with the data
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `value` attribute for anchor tag, Instead you can use [**data**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) .
Once the value is value of `data-someKey` is update in DOM , you can use

```
var getDataVal = document.getElementById('click_me').getAttribute('data-someKey')
```